# MVC4 SimpleMembership User.IsInRole throwing 'Invalid column name: UserId' error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I'm using SimpleMembership and on `Application_Start()`, I'm executing the following code:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyContext", "User", 
    "Id", "Email", autoCreateTables: true);
```

However, in my controller, when I execute the following line of code:

```
bool isAdmin = Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin");
```

I get the following error:

> Invalid column name 'UserId'.

Where would it be getting a reference to a UserId column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem...

webpages_Membership had a column called "Id" instead of "UserId". Doh.

Answer (score 0):

Are you set web config?

```
<roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="YourDbConnectionString" 
             applicationName="MySampleAppName"
             name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: No, I didn't have that set but adding it had no effect on the problem.

Comment: Please check your database and ensure that UserId column is exsist

Comment: Well it's obvious that it's looking for a UserId column that doesn't exist. :) My question is WHY is it looking for one since I explicitly defined my primary key column in InitializeDatabaseConnection to be "ID".

Comment: please check you userProfile model